Transformation of Probability Distributions: $g(z)=f(x)\frac{dx}{dz}$.
I am self-studying from the book Probability in Physics: An Introductory Guide by Lawrence, and came across the following segment at the top of section 2.6:
If we have a random variable $x$ then any function of that variable, $z=z(x)$, is also a random variable. If we have a mathematical expression for the PDF of $x$, say $f(x)$, then we can derive an expression for the PDF of $z$, $g(z)$ using the usual rules of calculus:
$$g(z)= f(x)\frac{dx}{dz}.$$
Now I am not sure what he means with the usual rules of calculus. What I came up by myself is the following by integrating with substitution:
$$1=\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)dx=\int^{z(\infty)}_{z(-\infty)}f(x)/\frac{dz}{dx}dz.$$
Then $g(z)$ can be assumed to be $f(x)/\frac{dz}{dx}$, but I don't know how to prove that. And even if we can, can we just take this expression and make $f(x)\cdot\frac{dx}{dz}$ from it? How do we know $\frac{dx}{dz}$ even exists, as the author doesn't say that $z(x)$ is invertible, i.e., $z'(x)\neq0$ anywhere?
I am not very good at this, so please, speak as you might to a young child, or a golden retriever.

It is perhaps easier to do an example. Say $\mu_X(dx) = f(x)dx$ and you define $Y = X^3$. Then $x = y^{1/3}$ and $dx = \frac{1}{3}y^{-2/3}dy$. Then plugging this in, we have $$\mu_Y(dy) = f(y^{1/3})\frac{1}{3} y^{-2/3}dy$$ In other words, $$P(Y\in B) = \int_B \frac{1}{3}f(y^{1/3})y^{-2/3}dy$$ If you want to prove this, then you probably shouldn't be reading a book called "probability for physicists."

Thank you @Andrew . So what I am getting from this: As a "physicist" I shouldn't worry too much about possible exceptions and such,  as long as I can do the same process as you did above? I am feeling uneasy about it, but don't know why, probably inexperience.


It is a bad habit in some areas of science to denote a random variable and the real argument of its PDF by the same letter ($z,x$ in your case). To make it worse (and create a lot of reasons to feel uneasy) you even
denote the function that relates the random variables $z$ and $x$ by $\color{red}z$ again.

Fixing all of this the PDF $g(z)$ of $\color{red}{Z=h(X)}$ can be derived from its CDF $G(z)$ and the PDF $f(x)$ of $\color{red}X$ almost in auto pilot mode:
$$
G(z)=\mathbb P\big\{Z\le z\big\}=\mathbb P\big\{h(X)\le z\big\}\,.
$$
When $h$ is invertible this is
$$
G(z)=\mathbb P\big\{X\le h^{-1}(z)\big\}=F(h^{-1}(z))
$$
where $F(x)$ is the CDF of $X\,.$

Now use the chain rule and the rule for differentiating inverse functions
to get the expression for the PDF $g(z)=G'(z)$ of $Z\,.$



Great, thank you. Then one last question remains: non-invertable h like Z=X^2 are ruled out in this formula, am I right?

Not quite :) Hint: show $G(z)=F(\sqrt{z})-F(-\sqrt{z}),.$
